# Column does not belong to table when Inserting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datatable

I'm trying to move data between two servers. I have an identical table on each server with 3 fields, Customer_Code(varchar), Customer_EmailAddress(nvarchar), Customer_EmailAddressPosted(bit).

```
Dim DT_EmailsToUpdatePreCheck As New DataTable
Dim DT_EmailsToUpdateStage As New DataTable
```

From Server1 I select all data and store into DT_EmailsToUpdatePreCheck

```
 TabletCommand.CommandText = "Select * from SOP_MissingCustomerEmail"
 DT_EmailsToUpdatePreCheck.Load(TabletCommand.ExecuteReader)
 TabletCommand.Parameters.Clear()
```

Then I iterate through DT_EmailsToUpdatePreCheck and get the count of records from Server2 where neither the Customer_Code nor the Customer_EmailAddress are identical and store the data into DT_EmailsToUpdateStage .

```
For j As Integer = 0 To DT_EmailsToUpdatePreCheck.Rows.Count - 1

            ServerCommand.CommandText = "Select Count(*) from SOP_MissingCustomerEmail where Customer_Code <> @Customer_Code and Customer_EmailAddress <> @Customer_EmailAddress"
            ServerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_Code", DT_EmailsToUpdatePreCheck.Rows(j).Item("Customer_Code"))
            ServerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_EmailAddress", DT_EmailsToUpdatePreCheck.Rows(j).Item("Customer_EmailAddress"))

            If ServerCommand.ExecuteScalar = 0 Then

                DT_EmailsToUpdateStage.ImportRow(DT_EmailsToUpdatePreCheck.Rows(j))
            End If

            ServerCommand.Parameters.Clear()
Next
```

Finally I iterate through DT_EmailsToUpdateStage to insert records into Server2

```
  For i As Integer = 0 To DT_EmailsToUpdateStage.Rows.Count - 1
            ServerCommand.CommandText = "Insert Into SOP_MissingCustomerEmail2 (Customer_Code, Customer_EmailAddress, Customer_EmailAddressPosted) Values (@Customer_Code, @Customer_EmailAddress, @Customer_EmailAddressPosted)"
            ServerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_Code", DT_EmailsToUpdateStage.Rows(i).Item("Customer_Code").ToString())
            ServerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_EmailAddress", DT_EmailsToUpdateStage.Rows(i).Item("Customer_EmailAddress").ToString())
            ServerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_EmailAddressPosted", DT_EmailsToUpdateStage.Rows(i).Item("Customer_EmailAddressPosted").ToString())

            MessageBox.Show("Row Inserted")
            ServerCommand.Parameters.Clear()
  Next
```

But in the Insert I get a "Column 'Customer_Code' does not belong to table" error. 
Note: The last two code blocks are inside a Try-Catch block.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the second loop in the debugger? Which line raises the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I managed to solve it. DT_EmailsToUpdateStage was not being populated properly. When creating the Datatables I had to dictate the column structure so that when calling the items by column name, it would be found.

```
    Dim DT_UpdateEmailStage1 As New DataTable
    DT_UpdateEmailStage1.Columns.Add("Customer_Code", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    DT_UpdateEmailStage1.Columns.Add("Customer_EmailAddress", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    DT_UpdateEmailStage1.Columns.Add("Customer_EmailAddressPosted", Type.GetType("System.String"))

    Dim DT_UpdateEmailStage2 As New DataTable
    DT_UpdateEmailStage2.Columns.Add("Customer_Code", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    DT_UpdateEmailStage2.Columns.Add("Customer_EmailAddress", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    DT_UpdateEmailStage2.Columns.Add("Customer_EmailAddressPosted", Type.GetType("System.String"))
```

I also changed the way I add the values to the row. First I put the values from the table into a variable then passed them as parameters in Rows.Add() rathar than using ImportRow()

```
            Dim code As String
            Dim email As String
            Dim posted As String

            code = DT_UpdateEmailStage1.Rows(j).Item(0)
            email = DT_UpdateEmailStage1.Rows(j).Item(1)
            posted = DT_UpdateEmailStage1.Rows(j).Item(2)

            If ServerCommand.ExecuteScalar = 0 Then
                DT_UpdateEmailStage2.Rows.Add(code, email, posted)
            End If
```

And a similar method when isnertinginto Server2

```
            Dim code As String
            Dim email As String
            Dim posted As String

            code = DT_UpdateEmailStage2.Rows(i).Item(0)
            email = DT_UpdateEmailStage2.Rows(i).Item(1)
            posted = DT_UpdateEmailStage2.Rows(i).Item(2)


            ServerCommand.CommandText = "insert into SOP_MissingCustomerEmail(customer_code, customer_emailaddress, customer_emailaddressposted) values (@customer_code, @customer_Emailaddress, @customer_EmailaddressPosted)"
            ServerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_code", code)
            ServerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_emailaddress", email)
            ServerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_emailaddressposted", posted)
```